# Test if a command outputs an empty string in vbscript

Tags: linux, vbscript, command, output, secure-crt

I have the following vbscript command:

```
crt.Screen.Send "cat myfile.txt | grep 'L[0-9]*' " &  vbcr
```

I want to know if there is a way to know if the command outputs anything or not, I need to do it in vbscript

Comment: Without knowing what the `crt` object is we can't help you. There should be a `Set crt = CreateObject("...")` further up in the code somewhere that defines what crt is or a `Set crt = new ...` if it's a VBScript class.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather from the limited example you have posted it looks as though you are using [VanDyke Software's SecureCRT](https://www.vandyke.com/products/securecrt/index.html) product which supports automation of tasks using scripting.

There is quite a detail [Scripting Essentials Guide](https://www.vandyke.com/support/tips/scripting/scripting_essentials.pdf) found on the software providers website.

In the guide it details how to capture data from a remote machine *(see 4.3 in the guide)*

> <sup>From [Scripting Essentials:
>   A Guide to Using
>   VBScript in SecureCRT](https://www.vandyke.com/support/tips/scripting/scripting_essentials.pdf)</sup>
>   *The following methods associated with the Screen object can be used to capture data via a
>   connection to a remote machine: `ReadString()`, `Get()`, and `Get2()`. Although SecureCRT's
>   logging capabilities can also be used to capture data from a remote device, the logging API is
>   referenced and discussed in a later chapter (Writing Data to Files Using the FileSystemObject). If
>   you're looking for ways to access data that is currently selected within the SecureCRT terminal
>   screen, please see the earlier section, Accessing Selected Text on the Screen.*

You may also find [this article](https://www.vandyke.com/support/tips/readstring.html) useful which explains how `ReadString()` works and gives an example of how to use it to capture command output into a variable.

The guide gives a basic of example of how using `ReadString()` works to retrieve a serial number from a Cisco device.

```
crt.Screen.Synchronous = True
' Send a command to a Cisco device to get the serial number
' of the device.
crt.Screen.Send "sh tech-support | in ([sS]erial)" & vbcr
' Wait for the CR to be echoed back to us so that what is
' read from the remote is only the output of the command
' we issued (rather than including the command issued along
' with the output).
crt.Screen.WaitForString vbcr
' Capture the result into a script variable
strResult = crt.Screen.ReadString("pixfirewall#")
' strResult will contain something like:
' Serial Number: 1850889413810201 (0x6935FC6075819)
MsgBox strResult
```

Which you should be able to modify to fit your requirement.

The example works on the premise that once the command is sent and the Carriage Return character *(Enter key in affect on Linux)* returned *(to denote the command has run)* it then uses `ReadString()` to capture the output but only once it detects the prompt `pixfirewall#` in the terminal window.